# Summing and grouping the number of records in a month

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following table which has employees' absence:

```
RecordId    EmpID       ActivityCode  DateFrom    DateTo
---------------------------------------------------------------
666542      1511        AB            29/01/2011  02/02/2011
666986      1511        AB            11/11/2011  11/11/2011
666996      1511        EL            13/11/2011  17/11/2011
755485      1787        SL            01/11/2011  14/11/2011
758545      1787        SL            15/11/2011  03/12/2011
796956      1954        AB            09/11/2011  09/11/2011
799656      1367        AB            09/11/2011  09/11/2011
808845      1527        EL            16/11/2011  16/11/2011
823323      1527        EL            17/11/2011  17/11/2011
823669      1527        EL            18/11/2011  18/11/2011
899555      1123        AB            09/11/2011  09/12/2011
990990      1511        AB            12/11/2011  12/11/2011
```

Now I want a report generated by a stored proc to sum all the absence days for a specific absence code for each month in a given year, for example If i want to know the totals of absence in 2011 from the previous table I will get something similar to:

```
Month        TotalDays
---------------------------------
JAN 2011     201
FEB 2011     36
MAR 2011     67
APR 2011     91
....
```

The stored proc will have two params (@Year INT, @AbsCode NVARCHAR(3)).
Please Note, Sometimes a record overlaps another month (like the first row in the example table) and that should be counted separately for each month. I have tried using loops but with no luck. I am so weak in TSQL.

**UPDATE**
Right now I am using a scalar value user function and a stored procedure to do the job, Its ugly and hard to trace. Here it is any way:

The User function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetActivityTotalDaysInMonth]
(
     @ActivityCode CHAR(3)
     ,@Year INT
     ,@Month INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @FirstDayOfMonth DATETIME
DECLARE @LastDayOfMonth DATETIME
SET @FirstDayOfMonth = CAST(CAST(@Year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
SET @LastDayOfMonth = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(M, 1, @FirstDayOfMonth))    

DECLARE @TotalDays INT

SELECT @TotalDays = 
SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, 
  (CASE WHEN ActivityDateFrom < @FirstDayOfMonth THEN @FirstDayOfMonth ELSE ActivityDateFrom END)
, (CASE WHEN ActivityDateTo > @LastDayOfMonth THEN @LastDayOfMonth ELSE ActivityDateTo END))+1)

FROM Activities 
WHERE 
ActivityCode=@ActivityCode
AND ((ActivityDateFrom < @FirstDayOfMonth AND ActivityDateTo >= @FirstDayOfMonth)
OR (ActivityDateFrom >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND ActivityDateTo <= @LastDayOfMonth)
OR (ActivityDateFrom <= @LastDayOfMonth AND ActivityDateTo > @LastDayOfMonth))
RETURN @TotalDays
END
```

Now, I call this function inside a loop in a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetAnnualActivityTotalDays
(
    @ActivityCode CHAR(3)
    ,@Year INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Stats TABLE
([Month] NVARCHAR(50), TotalDays INT)

DECLARE @MonthNo INT
DECLARE @Month DATETIME

SET @MonthNo = 1

WHILE @MonthNo <= 12
BEGIN

    SET @Month = CAST(CAST(@Year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@MonthNo AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO @Stats ([Month], TotalDays)
    SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(mm, @Month), 1, 3)) + ', ' + CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR),
    dbo.GetActivityTotalDaysInMonth(@ActivityCode
                ,@Year
                ,@MonthNo
                ,@Base)

    SET @MonthNo = @MonthNo + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @Stats
END
```

As you can see, this is ugly code which I believe it can be done in an easier way.. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a pretty nasty table structure too.  Putting in date ranges like that instead of individual dates can lead to all sorts of problems like employee 123 being absent twice on the same date (because the ranges overlap).

Comment: @JNK, No that never happens. This table is used for all sorts of activities not only absence and its so helpfull in this design, the only problem i had so far is this.

Comment: @HaLaBi that hasn't happened **yet** but your design allows it.  It's an unsafe design even if it is easy for most things.

Comment: @JNK ok, can you please give me a clear example when that might happen?

Comment: Two rows of data: `DATEFROM 12/15/2011 DATETO 12/17/2011`  `DATEFROM 12/16/2011 DATETO 12/18/2011` for the same employee - they were actually out for 4 days but you have a total of 6 days in your ranges.

Comment: There's no efficient way to check for overlaps in a design like this.  For a single date per row you could put a unique constraint on a combination for fields to enforce integrity.

Comment: no that never happens, The Stored proc which saves the activity checks for overlapping. In case any record is overlapped by any other record it will throw an exception. constraints!

Comment: of course there is efficient way, Triggers when adding records will do the job.. or a simple check before adding any record to the table in the same stored proc which adds the records.

Comment: Having the SP check it is not a constraint.  And you are basically adding processing overhead and trusting in the SP to prevent issues from occuring instead of preventing them at the design level.

Comment: Those aren't efficient - you need to check every record for that employee for any overlapping date.  That's the opposite of efficient.

Comment: ok. I respect your point. but there are other good reasons for chosing this design, Adding a record lets say for 30 days will be much easier than adding 30 records! deleting these records in case its added by mistake. what about editing this records.. isn't that over-heading?? you are right when it comes to checking for overlaps. but I am right for adding, deleting and updating..

Comment: @JNK, any way the database is on production and its ok for years. whats the solution now?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a calendar table which will allow you to easily count the days for each month that the start and end dates encompass. For example recordid = 666542 has 3 days in January and 2 days in February. You'd be able to get that number by a query like

```
select calyear, calmonth, caldate
from calendar
    join activities on calendar.caldate between activities.activitydatefrom and activities.activitydateto
where activitycode = 'AB'
```

If you wrap that in a common table expression you can perform aggregation queries afterwards on the CTE.

```
with mycte as (
select calyear, calmonth, caldate
from calendar
    join activities on calendar.caldate between activities.activitydatefrom and activities.activitydateto
where activitycode = 'AB'
)

select calyear, calmonth, count(caldate)
from mycte
group by calyear, calmonth
order by calyear, calmonth
```

To generate the calendar table you can use code similar to

```
create table calendar (calyear, calmonth, caldate)

declare @numdays int --number of days to generate in the calendar
declare @datestart datetime --the date to begin from in the calendar

set @numdays = 365 
set @datestart = 'jan 1 2011';

with num as (
select 0 number
union
select 1 number
union
select 2 number
union
select 3 number
union
select 4 number
union
select 5 number
union
select 6 number
union
select 7 number
union
select 8 number
union
select 9 number

),

numberlist as (
select ((hundreds.number * 100) + (tens.number * 10) + ones.number) n
from num hundreds
    cross join num tens 
    cross join num ones 
where ((hundreds.number * 100) + (tens.number * 10) + ones.number) < @numdays
)

insert into calendar (calyear, calmonth, caldate)
select 
    datepart(yy,dateadd(dd,n,@datestart)) calyear, 
    datepart(mm,dateadd(dd,n,@datestart)) calmonth, 
    dateadd(dd,n,@datestart)caldate
from numberlist
```